# How to clone/copy the behavior of a TextView object that has changed programmatically?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to clone the behavior of a TextView. I have already checked other threads about this topic and it is clear that the best way to do it is by inflating the widget through the view.findViewById(id) method. However, this way seems to provide only a copy of the static behavior of the TextView, that is, only the behavior defined in the XML. However, what I need to do is to copy the TextView's behavior that is changed programmatically, here is the context:

1. Below is my XML. In order to keep it simple, I will only focus on one thing: make the TextView scrollable (android:scrollbars="vertical") but have in mind that I need much more complex behavior on the TextView object than that.

```html
<TextView
             android:id="@+id/text_test"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="14sp"
             android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
             android:textStyle="italic"
             android:gravity="center_vertical"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:padding="5dp"
             android:textColor="#fff"
             android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
             android:text="Hello world"
             android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

2. In order to make the TextView scrollable, I also have to include these two lines on the inflate method of my Renderer class:

```js
TextView txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_test);
txtView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

3. Now, what I need to do is to create multiple copies (around 200) of the txtView object above. If I only inflate the widget by using the findViewById method, it will create a new TextView with the attributes defined in my XML but it won't contain a reference of the ScrollingMovementMethod object that I set to txtView through the setMovementMethod, so I would have to do it programmatically, something like this:

```js
TextView[] array = new TextView[200];
for( int i = 0; i < 200; i++ ){
    array[i] = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_test);
    array[i].setMovementMethod( txtView.getMovementMethod() );
    array[i].setEachMethodOfTextView( txtView.getEachMethodOfTextView() );
    ....
}
```

4. Now, the problem here is that I need to copy not only the movement method but also all kind of listeners and attributes that has changed dynamically on txtView. If I follow the same logic as in the previous step, I would have to follow a tedious and not elegant way of copying one by one each attribute from the base object (txtView) that has changed programmatically and dynamically. So, instead of that, I tried to use a deep cloning technique (using google guava library) but I got some StackOverflow erros since the TextView object contains more complex objects and nested references. Here is the log trace:

```js
12-31 12:38:12.165  27590-27590/example.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: example.your_app, PID: 27590
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at org.objenesis.instantiator.android.Android18Instantiator.newInstance(Android18Instantiator.java:44)
            at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
            at com.rits.cloning.ObjenesisInstantiationStrategy.newInstance(ObjenesisInstantiationStrategy.java:18)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.newInstance(Cloner.java:271)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:436)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:453)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:431)
            at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject
```

In summary, what I need to find out is how to clone/copy all the behavior of the TextView (and more generally, of any kind of widget view) without having to set one by one every attribute and method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think the solution is really, really simple: create a custom view that extends TextView, and set all those parameters inside this CustomView's constructor. Then use this custom view inside your xml.

You could maybe even move all those parameters you were setting inside your xml to the constructor to simplify the xml (something like this):

```
<your.package.view.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/text_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```